# How to check if a jquery obj contains another jquery obj?

Tags: jquery

If I have 2 jquery objects, how can I check if the first one contains the second one?

I also don't want to reference jquery itself, I want to use a method from the first jquery object, something like

```
<ul>
   <li></li>
</ul>

var obj1 = $("ul");
var obj2 = $("li");
obj1.contains(obj2)   --> true      [contains does not exist, how would I implement it?]
```

Comment: I assume you mean element within an element in the context of DOM?

Answer (score 0):

In order to test whether a given jQuery object contains another specific jQuery object, use the approach below; it returns *true* if the condition is satisfied, otherwise, *false*.

```js
var obj1 = $( "ul" );
var obj2 = $( "li" );

function checkForChildren( obj1, obj2 ) {
    if ( obj2[0].localName !== undefined && obj1.children( obj2[0].localName ).length > 0 )  {
        console.log( 'true' );
        return true;
    }
    console.log( 'false' );
    return false;
}
checkForChildren( obj1, obj2 );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @omega: re-updated again. Hope this time it meets your expectations!

Comment: Doesn't account for multi depth